# Types and higher-order function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Could someone help me to understand this issue.

I have this simple function:

```
takeAsLong :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
takeAsLong [] _ = []
takeAsLong (x:xs) test | test x    = x : takeAsLong xs test
                       | otherwise = []
```

But when I try to rewrite it using ***if-then-else*** I have an error.

```
takeAsLong :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
takeAsLong [] _ = []
takeAsLong (x:xs) test = if test x then x : takeAsLong [xs] test else []
```

The error is in the recursive call of "takeAsLong [xs] test" but I dont understand why it doesnt like it?

Error msg:

> Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a]’
> Expected: [a] -> Bool
> Actual: a -> Bool
> ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
> the type signature for:
> takeAsLong :: forall a. [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]

So why does it expect function test to be `[a] -> Bool` and why version with guards doesnt have same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xs` is a *list* of items except the first item. If you use `[xs]` then you wrapt that list in a singleton list.

You thus should call `takeAsLong xs test` instead of <s>`takeAsLong [xs] test`</s>:

```
takeAsLong :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
takeAsLong [] _ = []
takeAsLong (x:xs) test = if test x then x : takeAsLong xs test else []
```

Using an `if`-`then`-`else` is not that common. Usually the predicate will also be the first parameter. So a more "Haskell-ish" version is likely:

```
takeAsLong :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeAsLong p = go
    where go [] = []
          go (x:xs)
              | p x = x : go xs
              | otherwise = []
```

This function already exists and is known as [**`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile)

Comment: What a stupid mistake on my side. And error msg. actually make sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrej Don't worry about it. An important part of learning Haskell is learning to understand the GHC type error messages. They are very informative, but it takes a while to get the hang of figuring out what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is in the part `takeAsLong [xs]` when you do that you are giving to the function `takeAsLong :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]` a list of lists, `takeAsLong :: [[a]] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]` that type is the one would work, but you type is the other one.
There is how to do it in @willem answer:

```
takeAsLong :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
takeAsLong [] _ = []
takeAsLong (x:xs) test = if test x then x : takeAsLong xs test else []
```